# Pulseaudio equalizer not working

Tags: pulseaudio

Pulseaudio equalizer gui won't start, it gives this error when typed in terminal:

```
manevskifi4o@M-Ubuntu-13:~$ pulseaudio-equalizer-gtk
Getting settings...
/usr/bin/pulseaudio-equalizer: line 221: /home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/equalizerrc: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/presets’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/pulseaudio-equalizer: line 229: /home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/equalizerrc.availablepresets.unsorted: No such file or directory
sed: couldn't flush stdout: Broken pipe
/usr/bin/pulseaudio-equalizer: line 232: /home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/equalizerrc.availablepresets.unsorted: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/presets/*.preset: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/pulseaudio-equalizer: line 235: /home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/equalizerrc.availablepresets: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/equalizerrc.availablepresets.unsorted’: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pulseaudio-equalizer/pulseaudio-equalizer.py", line 535, in <module>
    Equalizer()
  File "/usr/share/pulseaudio-equalizer/pulseaudio-equalizer.py", line 357, in __init__
    GetSettings()
  File "/usr/share/pulseaudio-equalizer/pulseaudio-equalizer.py", line 46, in GetSettings
     f = open(eqconfig, "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/manevskifi4o/.pulse/equalizerrc'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it, create this folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.pulse/equalizerrc
```

Then run:

```
/usr/share/pulseaudio-equalizer/pulseaudio-equalizer.py
```

Comment: For some users it worked changing the second folder created names to `.equalizerrc` *(i.e. with a leading dot)*

Comment: What can we do if the `usr/share/pulseaudio-equalizer`folder doesn't exist?